# Can CME destroy planetary rings?

Tags: gas-giants, planetary-ring, coronal-mass-ejection

Is Corona Mass Ejection able to reach the outer planets such as Jupiter and Saturn? If so can it blows away the icy rings or the distance is simply beyond the reach of maybe like Earth it is protected by a magnetic field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it can reach both Saturn and Jupiter. But it's not powerful enough to remove their rings. Even Earth's radiation belts don't get blown away.

Edit: Jupiter's magnetic field is $\approx 770 \mu T$ (at the surface of its equator) which is way more powerful than Earth's ($\approx 40 \mu T$ at the equator). Saturn's magnetic field on the other hand is a tad less powerful than that of the Earth ($\approx 20 \mu T$ at its equator). So Earth's magnetosphere shields it's particles from CMEs. Jupiter is further away and its magnetosphere is way stronger than Earth's. So it shields everything effectively. Saturn is even further away and although its magnetic field is comparable to that of the Earth, the distance from the Sun assures us that a CME wouldn't have a significant impact of any sort there.

Comment: Any references or numbers would be great. As it is written now it looks like just an opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure how you want numbers on something that never happened (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_of_absence). Or are you speaking about writing up e.e. the stand-off distance of the magnetosphere and compare it to the ring size?